# How does the hexaaquacopper (II) form?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals

So the hexaaquacopper (II) ion has an octahedral structure with 6 aqua ligands datively bonded to the central Cu2+ cation:

[image: A hexaaquacopper (II) ion]

My question is: how is this possible if the electronic configuration of the Cu2+ cation is [Ar]4s-0 3d-9. This only leaves one empty 4s orbital and 3 4p orbitals available for dative bonding which would suggest that a tetraaqua complex should form but this is not the case?

Comment: 4d is participating.

Comment: How is this possible? Wouldn't the 4d be at too high of a level to participate?

Comment: @WeijunZhou It's not. OP's right.

Comment: @Mithoron This is from a highly phenomenological description that describes the central atom as undergoing $sp^3d^2$ hybridization (as in this figure which contains Chinese: [$sp^3d^2$ for Fe](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/%E9%93%81%E7%A6%BB%E5%AD%90sp3d2%E6%9D%82%E5%8C%96%E7%A4%BA%E6%84%8F.jpg/650px-%E9%93%81%E7%A6%BB%E5%AD%90sp3d2%E6%9D%82%E5%8C%96%E7%A4%BA%E6%84%8F.jpg) and that is what I have been taught years ago. I know that CFT and LFT are far better alternatives and I should be more careful next time in making comments.

Comment: @LemuelCrentsil The link above already pretty much answers your question, but you may wish to also learn about the alternative theory as listed [here](http://www.nios.ac.in/media/documents/313courseE/L24.pdf), which is still quite commonly used in some elementary courses. It's simple to understand, but not correct, and resulted in my comment above. You should always use CFT or LFT whenever possible.

Comment: @Weijin Zhou Thank you for your answer I will also have a look at CFT and LFT.